# R package development problem, unable to install my R package

Tags: r, package

I run R CMD check "folderlocation" to check my R package and I get the following in the result Git.Rcheck folder within the install.out file.

** installing *source* package 'SAEplus' ...

** using staged installation

** R

** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading

Error: package slot missing from signature for generic 'extent'
and classes sf
cannot use with duplicate class names (the package may need to be re-installed)
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'SAEplus'

** removing 'D:/Ify/Git/Git.Rcheck/SAEplus'

Does anyone know why this might be happening? I have gone as far as deleting all data from my data folder. There are no function examples in the R folder. The R folder only contains functions with their function documentation code.

Comment: Have you defined your own class `sf` and function `extent` in your package? or are you using those from another package? It's difficult to say what could be going on without being able to look at some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have not defined by own class "sf". However, my package uses the package "sf" for geospatial analysis. I never or used a function called extent.

Comment: I am not sure how to reproduce my package here. The package is on github but has to be private because some data is sensitive.

Comment: I ran Last.error.trace command and got the following: